# redundant <p></p> show in browser

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am practicing writing a html using bootstrap. I am a beginner. There is a strange error when i open my html file in my browser: there are no paragraph tags `<p></p>`in the source code, but they show in the browser.

Part of source code:

```html
<div class="header" style="background-image: url(http://www.cnblogs.com/skins/WebLoad/images/o_header.jpg">
        <header id="top" class="navbar navbar-static-top bs-docs-nav">
            <div class="container topbar">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <h1><b>Welcome to our home page！</b></h1>
                </div>
                <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a id="signin-out" class="cd-signin header-item" href="#0">login/register</a></li>
                        <li><a class="cd-signup header-item" href="#0">know more</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="name" class="bs-docs-header" tabindex="-1">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>team name</h1>
                <p>team desciption</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Browser shows :
[screenshot of display with paragraph space at top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qhVX.png)

When i use firebug to inspect it, it shows 
[code including paragraph tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94qjS.png)
redundant `<p></p>`

Comment: Give us the complete code. Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: can you share full html source code with body tag.

Comment: no in this code there is no `p` element unless in your complete code there is some script that append this element ..

Comment: I have inspected my code again, and found there is a `<p>` in `<head></head>`, after I delete it, the browser showed normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yogesh Chauhan: **Main reasons for empty p tags could be**:

1. You are using online visual text editor for writing your code and hitting
   enter for a new line
2. While writing HTML code you are hitting enter for a new line
3. Usage of :empty CSS property in HTML

If you still have empty p tags in your HTML, then you can use javascript or jQuery to check for empty p tags and remove them.

**Here is the code example for removing empty p tags usings jQuery. To implement this follow point**:

1. Include latest jQuery library in the header part of HTML
2. Before closing body tag write the code
   `<script> $('p:empty').remove(); </script>`

This will remove all the empty p tags from your page.

```js
$('p:empty').remove();
```

```css
p { height: 30px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Before empty p tags</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p>After empty p tags</p>

<div class="header" style="background-image: url(http://www.cnblogs.com/skins/WebLoad/images/o_header.jpg">

  <header id="top" class="navbar navbar-static-top bs-docs-nav">
    <div class="container topbar">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <h1><b>Welcome to our home page！</b></h1>
      </div>
      <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a id="signin-out" class="cd-signin header-item" href="#0">login/register</a></li>
          <li><a class="cd-signup header-item" href="#0">know more</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="name" class="bs-docs-header" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>team name</h1>
      <p>team desciption</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you do not have anything on your body tag ?

Maybe it's just the cache of your browser that needs refresh (crtl + shift + R or cmd + shift + R)

You can also check if you do not have in your code a javascript plugin that adds code (in this p tag).